# Deploy to Azure Websites fails (wrong framework?)

Tags: azure, deployment, bitbucket, azure-web-app-service

When i try to deploy from source control (Bitbucket), it fails, and seems to choose the wrong framwork?

I did as follows:

1. Create empty 4.5 MVC project in VS 2013
2. Run: install-package umbracocms
3. Create .hgignore to ignore stuff like (/bin, /obj, /media)
4. hg push to BitBucket (https://bitbucket.org/TheBekker/umbracotest)

Not sure if or what i'm doing wrong here?

Here is my deployment log:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8528656

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

For some reason SQLCE was included, and was trying to get the files from /bin folder (witch isnt checked in to source control) + a dummy.txt file in /media.

Removing all those from .proj file, and redeploying fixed the issue